How to create dropdown menu?
I need to make a dropdown menu when clicked. I know how to do it for one button, but I don't know how to do it for several buttons.
const submenuBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".submenu-btn");
const submenuContent = document.querySelectorAll(".submenu-content");
const toggleMenuBox = () => {
  submenuContent.forEach(item => item.classList.toggle("active"));
};
submenuBtn.forEach(event => event.addEventListener("click", () => {
  toggleMenuBox();
}))


Please visit [ask] and markdown editing help

I suggest you look up event delegation

What stops you from doing this?  At a glance of the code shown, it appears that you're trying to toggle every submenuContent element when clicking any submenuBtn element.  Is that what you want to do?  If you want to only toggle one such element, how would you identify the one you want?

I have several buttons, and I need each button to define its own content.

@ВиталийКравченко: And what attempt do you make to do that?  For example, in your markup how do you identify which "content" is associated with which "button"?  What stops you from using that information in the click handler?  Currently the code toggles all contents for every click.  When you try to target a specific content, what problem do you encounter?

Could you show me an example? The problem is that all the buttons call the same content, but I need different ones

@ВиталийКравченко: For example, you might add a data-* attribute to each submenuBtn element, and in that attribute specify an id for its corresponding submenuContent element.  Then in the click handler you would get that attribute value from the element which was clicked and pass that value to toggleMenuBox which could use it to select the specific element to toggle, rather than toggling all of the elements.
